# "State" pattern and encapsulation

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, engineering, typescript

Suppose we have the following classes:

[image: Uml Diagram]

As you see, it's an implementation of the [State Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state).

Basically, the `Order` class proxies the `pay()` and `cancel()` method calls to it's concrete `OrderState` instance.

After executing their part of business logic, the `PendingOrderState` and `PaidOrderState` call `setState` on the `Order` instance to switch to other state.

### Question(s):

1. Is it a code smell, that the public API of the `Order` class is "polluted" by `setState`, a method which should only be used internally by the `OrderState` instances?
2. If the answer to the above question is "Yes", then how can the `setState` be encapsulated away from other clients of the Order class (like a hypothetical `Customer` class, who is only concerned with `pay` and `cancel` methods of the `Order`)?

### Possible Solution:

A possible solution that comes to my mind is introducing some kind of `OrderWrapper` class, that would wrap the `Order` class and only expose the `pay()` and `cancel()` methods.

P.S

Sorry for the sloppy attempt at UML :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a code smell that a "internal" function like `setState` gets exposed on the public interface of `Order`.

What you can do about it depends to a large extent on the design of your classes and the facilities that your implementation language provides.

In a language like Java, if `Order` and the concrete `OrderState` implementations belong to the same package, then you could give `setState` the "package private" access specifier, making it clear that only members of the same package are allowed to use that method.

In C++, you could trade the code smell of a too large public API for the code smell of specifying the concrete 'OrderState' implementations as friends of 'Order'. That would make it possible to make `setState` private, but `Order` effectively has to know about all states that it can be in, and those state implementations have a very broad access to `Order`. You would have to choose which solution smells the least to you.

In other languages, there might not be a way to remove the smell and you will have to live with it.

Comment: Unfortunately non of these methods work for me, as my codebase is written in `Typescript`. Thanks for confirming that it's a code smell, though.